# Grouping by in Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Am asked to prepare a chart and I have an issue and seeking help here,

**Here is my Scenario:**
   I have an EmployeeID, each day when the employee logs in there will be a transaction id auto generated, for this transaction id there will be 4 jobs running (Example: JobA, JobB, JobC, JobD)

**Example:** DayWiseReport (All I need is on a day how many emp is Completed/Failed)

TranID  EmpID      JobName     Status

835 014COMUS    NEXUS   Completed

835 014COMUS    GCM     Completed

835 014COMUS    OM      Completed

835 014COMUS    EUC     Failed

831 132COMUS    DSA     Completed

831 132COMUS    GCM     Completed

831 132COMUS    OM      Completed

Now, if a put a Pivot it says for given date 6-Completed and 1 Failed

But, what I need for a given date is:  1-Completed and 1-Failed

Thanks in Advance,

Satish D

Answer (score 0):

Where is date filed in this data set, if you add the date field you can plot the chart like below

[image]

Comment: This is what exactly even I get, But from your example the result I could required is 2 Failed that's all.                                                                                                                 As there are 2 employee (014, 132)  and when I do a group by TranID both has a failure result so my overall report has to fail